# Bad formating with align + cases and long equations

Tags: align, cases

This is what I have so far:

> [image: formatted badly]

Formatting in section 1 is a joke. I can't even read the cases. Under section 2 I cheated with a manual line break `\\` and a `parbox`. Still the result disgusts me.

What I would like to achieve is, that the equation number stays in front of the equation. Too long equation are broken automatically after `\textwidth` has been reached and that the cases text starts right after the comma and behaves like normal text in regard to line breaks and text length. I don't know if other math environments are better suited for this (I am pretty used to `align`) and if i can somehow control the cases environment better.

*Small sidenote: When breaking the equation manually before the `\right]` it won't get typesetted anymore*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Unformated Solution}
    \begin{align}
    E_{h,betr} =
    \begin{cases}
    \left[ \left(Q_{h,li0} + Q_{h,li} \times GHZ \right) + f_{h,rech} + E_{e,hilf,spez} \times f_{e,prim} \right] \times A_{ebf} \times f_{h,red}, &wenn Lebenszyklus des Gebäudes kein Vielfaches des Lebenszyklus der Heizung ist\\
    \left[ \left(Q_{h,li0} + Q_{h,li} \times GHZ \right) + f_{h,rech} + E_{e,hilf,spez} \times f_{e,prim} \right] \times A_{ebf} \times f_{h,red} + E_{h,erst} + E_{h,ent}, wenn Lebenszyklus des Gebäudes ein Vielfaches des Lebenszyklus der Heizung ist
    \end{cases}
    \end{align}

\section{Formated Solution} 
\begin{align}
E_{h,betr} =
\begin{cases}
\left[ \left(Q_{h,li0} + Q_{h,li} \times GHZ \right) + f_{h,rech} + E_{e,hilf,spez} \times f_{e,prim} \right] \times \\ A_{ebf} \times f_{h,red}, 
&\parbox[t]{0.3\textwidth}{wenn Lebenszyklus des Gebäudes kein Vielfaches des Lebenszyklus der Heizung ist} \\
\left[ \left(Q_{h,li0} + Q_{h,li} \times GHZ \right) + f_{h,rech} + E_{e,hilf,spez} \times f_{e,prim} \right] \times \\ A_{ebf} \times f_{h,red} + E_{h,erst} + E_{h,ent}, 
&\parbox[t]{0.3\textwidth}{wenn Lebenszyklus des Gebäudes ein Vielfaches des Lebenszyklus der Heizung ist}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may be interested in the [breqn package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/breqn).

Comment: @Ulrich Schwarz : Will look into that. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your equations are sufficiently long and that there's so much text to describe each of the two "cases" as to make the `cases` environment unsuitable to the task at hand. I think you're be better off using the `\intertext` command and simply typesetting the description of the first "case" between the two parts of the equation; place the text describing the second case *after* the end of the `align` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E} % expectation operator 
\newcommand{\GHZ}{\textit{GHZ}}  % define some variable names
\newcommand{\betr}{\textit{betr}}
\newcommand{\rech}{\textit{rech}}
\newcommand{\hilf}{\textit{hilf}}
\newcommand{\spez}{\textit{spez}}
\newcommand{\prim}{\textit{prim}}
\newcommand{\ebf}{\textit{ebf}}
\newcommand{\red}{\textit{red}}
\newcommand{\erst}{\textit{erst}}
\newcommand{\ent}{\textit{ent}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\E_{h,\betr} &=
\big[ (Q_{h,li0} + Q_{h,li} \times \GHZ \,) + f_{h,\rech} \\
&\qquad + \E_{e,\hilf,\spez} \times f_{e,\prim} \big] \times A_{\ebf} \times f_{h,\red}\notag\\
\intertext{wenn Lebenszyklus des Gebäudes kein Vielfaches des Lebenszyklus der Heizung ist, und}
&= \big[ (Q_{h,li0} + Q_{h,li} \times \GHZ \,) + f_{h,\rech} \notag\\
&\qquad + \E_{e,\hilf,\spez} \times f_{e,\prim} \big] \times A_{\ebf} \times f_{h,\red} 
    + \E_{h,\erst} + \E_{h,\ent}\notag
\end{align} 
wenn Lebenszyklus des Gebäudes ein Vielfaches des Lebenszyklus der Heizung ist.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. I think I will get the best result if I follow your advice. Maybe if I mix your solution with the comment from Ulrich Schwarz there need be no manual line breaks in the equation.